# MySQL 5.7.31 View is slower than query

Tags: mysql, sql-view

I have a select query. It takes 700 milliseconds, when i explain it results like this;

[Select Query Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im1UJ.png)

When I put it in a view, it taking 40 seconds. What can i do for this?

explain select * from view_stok;

[View Query Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gARzJ.png)

Comment: can you provide your table design, it will help people to help your question better

Comment: Your observations seem very doubtful to me.  Are you certain you reproduce this?  Note that the performance of a view should be roughly identical to the underlying query.

Comment: I tried with mysql sakila database, you can check actor_info view. It has same problem. 

If you look view's sql explain => PRIMARY it gives 200 rows.

When i do same thing with view explain it gives 5461 rows.

if i run first time => select * from actor_info it taken 1.700ms but view's query 370ms.